# How to create a length prefix for file being sent on socket?

Tags: c#, java, sockets, tcp

I want to send an `xml` file from a c# application to a java android app via tcp sockets.

The length of that xml file could vary wildly so I figure I need to prepend something to identify the length of that xml file at the start of the message. Socket.SendFile(..) has a parameter for this and I've started coding:

```
long fileLength = xmlFile.BaseStream.Length;
byte[] prepend = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileLength);
xmlFile.Close();

client.SendFile("test.xml", prepend, null, TransmitFileOptions.UseDefaultWorkerThread);
```

My problem is, In theory this application should run across a few different operating systems and on different pc's. Although for the most part things should be the same I'm worried about how to handle the situation where `long` is not 64 bits, which I believe could be possible?

In my java android app **I will be expecting the first 8 bytes to be a long representing the size of my xml file in bytes.. and the rest I will parse back into an xml file.But if the host machine running the c# application doesn't use 64 bits won't this cause a big issue?**

If so any suggestions for how to solve it? The only silly sounding thing I can come up with is to send a prefix byte to my prefix representing the number of bytes for the long I'm about to receive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, a [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) is just another alias for `System.Int64`. No matter what machine you are on, an Int64 is always 64 bits.

Comment: Ah that's good to know, I was under the impression that it might be different dependending on the size of the register.